# Jupyter Notebook only has Python [conda root] and Python [default] kernels

Tags: python, kernel, jupyter, conda

I followed all the steps outlined in the other Python [root] posts, but still cannot get the python2 and python3 kernels to show up.

Here is what my Jupyter notebook shows:

[image: Jupyter notebook]

and here is the startup log:

[image]

I have Anaconda3 installed (the 3.5 version).

How do I get the python2 and python3 kernels to show up?

Comment: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1630 - the other posts I was referring to. I don't have a high enough reputation to post more than two links in a post.

Comment: Yes, it's an anaconda thing. I think if you directly install jupiter using pip, you should see the python2 and python3 kernels. Guess this is more of a work around and not a solution, but it might solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

I have the similar situation as yours and I solved it through:

1. Switch to the conda env you wanna show in Jupyter notebook

> >>> source activate conda_env_name

2. Install/reinstall Jupyter under this env using:

> (conda_env_name)>>> conda install jupyter

You should be able to see your env under Jypyter Kernel->Change kernels lists (this is my first stackoverflow answer, hope it helps you)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue but i had python 2.7.12 installed from anaconda and the default one came with Mac is 2.7.10.

When i open jupiter notebook, i used to get Python[conda root] and Python[default], after lot of struggling i did the following

**conda update conda**

**conda uninstall ipython**

**conda install jupyter**

now i see only 'Python 2' in my Jupiter notebook

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I was stucked like you, and the solution is easy:
For more information: https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/jupyter-notebook-extensions#notebook-conda

In the HOME of jupiter Notebook you will find: Files, Running, Clusters and Conda
Select Conda
Then there is a space for the conda environments, there is a sign +, clic on it to add a new environment, here you can select conda 2 or 3, depends on you, and give a name, it could be the same name Conda 3.
After that you refresh environment list, and then close jupyter notebook.
Finally, open it again, and it should works.